# Running multiple functions without typing them all out one after another

Tags: python-3.x, function

So lets say I have a whole bunch of functions

```py
def my_Function1():
    do x

def my_Function2():
    do y

def my_Function3():
    do z

my_Function1()
my_Function2()
my_Function3()
```

Is there a way I could write another function that would execute these one by one without explicitly having to type "my_Functionx() multiple times. Or at least is there a more elegant way of going about this?

Comment: You've defined `my_Function1` 3 times; don't think that's what you meant to do.

Comment: @ScottHunter Thanks for pointing out the mistake, they are labelled correctly now

Answer (score 0):

You could write:

```
for f in (my_Function1,my_Function2,my_Function3):
    f()
```

Not sure how much more "elegant" that is.